# get ajax response from an PHP codeigniter API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, codeigniter

well my problem is the following, I'm developing a Codeigniter API (I'm not familiar with this framework and it's my first time building an API), I've followed a simple tutorial to make a very basic API, this is the controller:

```
/**
* @route http://proyect/users
* @verb GET
*/
public function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from `jobs`");

            return json_encode($query);

}

/**
* @route http://proyect/users
* @verb POST
*/
public function store($data)
{
    /*$data = array(
        'jobs_id' => '123',
        'jobs_name' => 'Programing',
        'jobs_category' => 'Programacion'
    );*/

    $this->db->insert('jobs', $data);
    // Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My id', 'My name', 'My category')
}

/**
* @route http://proyect/users
* @verb PUT
*/
public function update($data)
{
    /*$data = array(
        'jobs_id' => '0',
        'jobs_name' => 'My Name2',
        'jobs_category' => 'My category'
    );*/

    $this->db->set('jobs_name', $data['jobs_name']);
    $this->db->where('jobs_id', $data['jobs_id']);
    $this->db->update('jobs'); // gives UPDATE `mytable` SET `field` = 'field+1' WHERE `id` = 2
}

/**
* @route http://proyect/users
* @verb DELETE
*/
public function delete($data)
{
    /*$data = array(
        'jobs_id' => '123',
        'jobs_name' => 'My Name2',
        'jobs_category' => 'My category'
    ); */

    $this->db->delete('jobs', array('jobs_id' => $data['jobs_id']));  // Produces: // DELETE FROM mytable  // WHERE id = $id    
}
```

the get method works calling it from the URL and show me the results, the problem comes when I call it from an ajax, it recognize the url but does not give me the results, I think it's because I'm not returning the data conrrectly; this is my js calling the method:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTTP Referer example</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        var url = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/jobs/get';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data)
            }
        });              
    });
</script>

</body>
```

what I want is to retrieve that data from the database and have it shown in the console

Comment: Add content type for the data you are sending via ajax in your ajax call

`contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8'`

Comment: still with this the console shows null, but the method works, I'm Sure about it... it should show me something at the very least

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally could do it, in the method I needed to put this: `echo json_encode($query->result());` instead of: `return json_encode($query->result());` since it's json, so u need to echo it not return it yay!